# Continuity of functions and rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I saw this argument used in a proof, and I don't quite understand it with the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition (it is easier to understand with the sequential criterion).

If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at any point $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then suppose for any rational number $r$, $f(r)=r$. Clearly, it follows that using the fact that $f$ is continuous, then $f(x) = x$ ($\forall x \in \mathbb{R})$.

What would be the logic behind this argument? I've seen it being used in similar ways on many other proofs.

Comment: For any $x$, there is a sequence $(r_n)$ of rationals with limit $x$ (this is if you want to use sequences). Or else for any $\delta\gt 0$, there is a rational $r$ such that $0\lt |x-r|\lt delta$.

Comment: The "sequential" criterion is just a statement about limits. The epsilon-delta criterion is so too. You can go from one to the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct a sequence $\left(x_n\right)$ of rational numbers converging to an arbitrary real number, $x$ (the rationals are dense in the reals, so you can always do this). Since $f$ is continuous, then $x_n=f\left(x_n\right)\rightarrow f\left(x\right)$ (continuous functions and limits "commute"). Since limits are unique (this is true for any Hausdorff space), then $f\left(x\right)=x$.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=x$ instead of $f(x_n)\to x$ in your last sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Consider irrational $a$; by assumption $f$ is continuous here. Assume, for contradiction, that $f(a) = b \neq a$, and let $\sigma = b - a$ (assume, without loss of generality, that $b > a$).

Now, take any $\epsilon < \dfrac12\sigma$. By continuity, there is a $\delta$ so that

$$
|f(a) - f(x)| = |b - f(x)| < \epsilon
$$

whenever $|a - x| < \delta$. In particular, for rational $r \in (a - \delta,a+\delta)$,

$$
|b - r| < \epsilon < \dfrac12 \sigma.
$$

Let $r$ be a rational number in $(a - \delta,a)$, then

$$|b - r| = |b - a + a - r| = b - a + a - r> \sigma > \dfrac12\sigma > \epsilon,$$
and we have our contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the thing I don't really understandis how we are able to pick our $\delta$ in advance? Wasn't that true for $\epsilon$?

Comment: We don't; $\delta$ is given to us by continuity. Later, I choose $r \in (a - \delta,a)$, but: 1) you can always choose points in a *smaller* interval and 2) I'm only doing this to make the signs work out easily, it would hold for $r \in (a, a + \delta)$ as well.